# Select columns as rows

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

```
select * from emp14;
```

Output:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   EMAIL   
100          Steven            King         SKING
```

I want to display the output in column wise as follows:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID  100
FIRST_NAME   Steven
LAST_NAME    King
EMAIL        SKING
```

Comment: That link may not be exactly what you're looking for.  But this question is asked frequently, and if you search SO you'll find what you need.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+pivot?sort=votes&pagesize=30

Comment: @APC I think the duplicate is wrong, the OP wants to unpivot not pivot the data.

Comment: @bluefeet - I agree, your suggestion is more relevant

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT col, val
FROM
(
  SELECT to_char(EMPLOYEE_ID) AS EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME, EMAIL FROM emp14
)t 
UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS
( 
  VAL FOR col IN (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME, EMAIL)
);
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a742a/11)

Comment: +1 This is the neatest solution - providing the OP is on 11g or higher

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want each column displayed on a separate line.  The results of running a SELECT statement will be displayed in whatever manner the particular tool used to run the query chooses.  If you really want each column displayed on a separate line you can use a little PL/SQL:

```
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT * FROM EMP14) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPLOYEE_ID  ' || aRow.EMPLOYEE_ID);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FIRST_NAME   ' || aRow.FIRST_NAME);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LAST_NAME    ' || aRow.LAST_NAME);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMAIL        ' || aRow.EMAIL);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
-- this type is going to contain value's name and the value itself
SQL> create type t_data is object(
  2    col1 varchar2(31),
  3    col2 varchar2(31)
  4  );
  5  /

Type created


SQL> create type t_table is table of t_data;
  2  /

Type created
```

After that, the query can be constructed the following way:

```
-- sample of data from the question + some extra  data 
-- just for the sake of demonstration.
SQL> with t1(EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL) as
  2  (  select 100, 'Steven', 'King', 'SKING' from dual union all
  3     select 101, 'Steven1', 'King1', 'SKING1' from dual
  4   )
  5  select col1
  6       , col2
  7    from t1 t
  8    cross join table(
  9                     t_table( t_data('Employee_id', t.employee_id)
 10                             , t_data('First_name', t.first_name)
 11                             , t_data('Last_Name' , t.last_name)
 12                             , t_data('e-mail'    , t.email)
 13                             )
 14                     )
 15  ;
```

Result:

```
COL1                            COL2
------------------------------- -------------------------------
Employee_id                     100
First_name                      Steven
Last_Name                       King
e-mail                          SKING
Employee_id                     101
First_name                      Steven1
Last_Name                       King1
e-mail                          SKING1

8 rows selected
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select concat('EMPLOYEE_ID ', EMPLOYEE_ID) as EMPLOYEE_ID,
       concat( 'FIRST_NAME ' ,   FIRST_NAME) as FIRST_NAME,
       concat('LAST_NAME ' ,  LAST_NAME) as LAST_NAME,
       concat('EMAIL ' , EMAIL)  as EMAIL 
from email
```

Comment: For future reference, `+` is not a valuable concatenation operator in Oracle.

Comment: This returns one row. The OP wants "columns as rows".

Comment: That's right, I wrote as per mysql.

Comment: No i want to do it in Sql itself not in pl/sql...in sql we have row to column function...using that we can...

Comment: RAMKUMAR - I think you commented on the wrong post.  This seems to be directed to @BobJarvis